# Enviar dados via POST com ajax jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou treinando Ajax e JQuery, estou fazendo um simples comando para enviar dados via post e estou encontrando bastante dificuldade. Poderiam me ajudar?

Meu js está assim:

```
$('#cadastrarDespesa').on('click', function() {
  
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'incluir_despesa.php',
      datatype: 'html',
      data: {
        'data_despesa': $('#data_despesa').val(),
        'tipo': $('#tipo').val(),
        'valor': $('#valor').val(),
        'formaPgto': $('#formaPgto').val(),
        'conta': $('#conta').val(),
        'descricao': $('#descricao').val()     
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
        
        requisitarPagina('incluir_despesa.php #teste')
  
    })

})

function requisitarPagina(url) {

    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = ''
      
    let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

  
    ajax.open('GET', url)

    //de alguma lógica que fique olhando para o progresso da req
    ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
  
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = ajax.responseText
      }
  
      if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 404) {
  
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = '.. tente novamente mais tarde :s ..'
      }
    }
  
    ajax.send()
    //console.log(ajax)
  }
```

O PHP que recebe assim:

```
<?php 

    $data_despesa = $_POST['data_despesa'];
    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
    $valor = $_POST['valor'];
    $formaPgto = $_POST['formaPgto'];
    $conta = $_POST['conta'];
    $descricao = $_POST['descricao'];

?>

<p id="teste">
    <p><?= $data_despesa ?></p>
    <p><?= $tipo ?></p>
    <p><?= $valor ?></p>
    <p><?= $formaPgto ?></p>
    <p><?= $conta ?></p>
    <p><?= $descricao ?></p>
</p>
```

O PHP apenas informa que a variavel nao foi definida.

Warning: Undefined array key "data_despesa" in C:\xampp\htdocs\finthathi\incluir_despesa.php on line 13

Warning: Undefined array key "tipo" in C:\xampp\htdocs\finthathi\incluir_despesa.php on line 14

Warning: Undefined array key "valor" in C:\xampp\htdocs\finthathi\incluir_despesa.php on line 15

Warning: Undefined array key "formaPgto" in C:\xampp\htdocs\finthathi\incluir_despesa.php on line 16

Warning: Undefined array key "conta" in C:\xampp\htdocs\finthathi\incluir_despesa.php on line 17

Warning: Undefined array key "descricao" in C:\xampp\htdocs\finthathi\incluir_despesa.php on line 18

Quem puder ajudar fico muito agradecido!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Imprima o valor de `$_POST` com o método 
`<?php
var_dump($_POST);
exit();`
Aí você consegue ver o que está chegando, pois se chegar um `stdClass` ou `array`, por exemplo, vai ter que acessar de outra forma.

Answer (score 0):

Você está escrevendo atributo do objeto errado.

```
data: {
   'data_despesa': $('#data_despesa').val(),
   'tipo': $('#tipo').val(),
   'valor': $('#valor').val(),
   'formaPgto': $('#formaPgto').val(),
   'conta': $('#conta').val(),
   'descricao': $('#descricao').val()    
}
```

Enquanto deveria ser assim sem os aspas:

```
data: {
   data_despesa: $('#data_despesa').val(),
   tipo: $('#tipo').val(),
   valor: $('#valor').val(),
   formaPgto: $('#formaPgto').val(),
   conta: $('#conta').val(),
   descricao: $('#descricao').val()    
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, fiz assim e deu certinho! Obrigado!
Depois também encontrei uma forma muito boa de fazer isso que é usando o data: frm.serialize()

Comment: Que bom que resolveu o problema. Por favor poste a solução para mais pessoas aprenderem, e também marcar a pergunta como resolvido.